# Where should I post my question about product development?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm developing a [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) product, but I've difficulties with the pricing.

Currently I can't find any Stack Exchange site that has something to do with product development.

Where should I post my question?

Comment: It probably could've fit on [Startups](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62811/startups) but that was shutdown for inactivity.

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking for an alternative..

Comment: @Michiel There is no such site. Startups was created because there was no such site. Now that Startups is dead, again there is no such site.

Comment: @DanBron that's really unfortunate...

Comment: Well, what about proposing a new site on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)?